# Normal approximations to the posterior distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, bayesian

I'm reading about Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman et al. and I'm a little bit confused about how the author approximates posterior density by normal approximation. He first makes the Taylor series expansion for the logarithm of the posterior distribution under consideration:

> $$\log \,p(\theta \,|\, y) = \log \,p(\hat{\theta} \,|\, y)+
>  \frac12(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2\left[\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2} \log
>  \,p(\theta \,|\, y)\right]_{\theta=\hat{\theta}}+\cdots\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Then he states that

> Linear term in $(1)$ is zero because the log-posterior density has zero derivative at its mode. Considering $(1)$ as a function of $\theta$, the first
>   term is a constant, whereas the second term is proportional to the
>   logarithm of a normal density, yielding the approximation,
>
> $$p(\theta \,|\, y) \approx N\left(\hat{\theta},
>  \left[I(\hat{\theta})\right]^{-1}\right),$$
>
> where $$I(\theta)=-\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\,\log \,p(\theta \,|\, y)$$
>
> is the *observed information*.

This escaped me a little, so I tried to break this down more:

$$p(\theta \,|\, y) \approx N\left(\hat{\theta},
 \left[I(\hat{\theta})\right]^{-1}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi/I(\hat{\theta})}}\,\exp\left( -\frac12(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2I(\hat{\theta})\right)$$

$$\log \,p(\theta\,|\,y)\approx \frac12\log\left(\frac{I(\hat{\theta})}{2\pi}\right)-\frac12(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2I(\hat{\theta})$$

$$= \frac12\left[\log\left(-\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\,\log \,p(\hat{\theta} \,|\, y)\right)-\log2\pi\right]+\frac12(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\,\log \,p(\hat{\theta} \,|\, y)\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

So this result that I got isn't quite the same as in $(1)$? Did I do something wrong in the math or what is my malfunction here now x)

Thank you for your help! Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have gotten it myself, correct me please if I'm wrong:

The expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same with the exception of the constant terms. In $(1)$ the constant term is:

$$C_1=\log\,p(\hat{\theta}\,|\,y),$$

since $\hat{\theta}$ and $y$ are not variables. Similarly in $(2)$ the constant term is:

$$C_2=\frac12\left[\log\left(-\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\,\log \,p(\hat{\theta} \,|\, y)\right)-\log2\pi\right].$$

We can write $(1)$ as:

$$\log\,p(\theta\,|\,y) = C_1-\frac12(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2I(\hat{\theta})=C_1-\frac12\frac{(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2}{I(\hat{\theta})^{-1}},$$

$$ p(\theta\,|\,y) = \exp\left(C_1\right)\exp\left(-\frac12\frac{(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2}{I(\hat{\theta})^{-1}}\right)\approx N\left(\hat{\theta},
 \left[I(\hat{\theta})\right]^{-1}\right)=\exp\left(C_2\right)\exp\left(-\frac12\frac{(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2}{I(\hat{\theta})^{-1}}\right),$$

so the posterior density is proportional to normal distribution:

$$p(\theta\,|\,y) \propto N\left(\hat{\theta},
 \left[I(\hat{\theta})\right]^{-1}\right)=\exp\left(C_2\right)\exp\left(-\frac12\frac{(\theta-\hat{\theta})^2}{I(\hat{\theta})^{-1}}\right)$$

Comment: i think that's correct. well done

Comment: Thank you for your help @tired =)